# Is it possible to GroupBy multiple columns in JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, group-by, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem with a GroupBy query.

What I want to achieve is a GroupBy by multiple paramaters, I explain, If I do a

`select param1, count(paramX) from Table group by param1`

works fine, but If I do a

`select param1, param2. param3, count(paramX) from Table group by param1, param2, param3`

it fails in Hibernate, but the generated query extracted from logs, works finde in SQL IDE.

The project is a `SpringBoot(v2.1.4)` application in `Java8` that uses `Hibernate(v5.4.0)` and `Oracle12`.

Could it be that Hibernate does not allow GroupBy with multiple columns or do I have an error that I don´t see?

I show the code to have a better explanation:

```
final CriteriaBuilder critBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<CarTaskByOperator> critQuery = critBuilder.createQuery(CarTaskByOperator.class);
final Root<CarTaskOperationHist> root = critQuery.from(CarTaskOperationHist.class);

// Select and Group Expressions
final Expression<Long> exOperatorId = root.get("operatorId");
final Expression<String> exOperatorName = root.get("operatorBean").get("name");
final Expression<String> exMoment = critBuilder.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, 
root.get("moment"), critBuilder.literal("DD-MM-YYYY"));
final Expression<String> exType = 
root.get("carTaskBean").get("carIncidenceBean").get("carIncidenceTypeBean").get("description");
final Expression<Long> exAmount = critBuilder.count(root.get("incidenceId"));

final CriteriaQuery<CarTaskByOperator> select = critQuery.multiselect(exOperatorId, exOperatorName, exMoment, exType, exAmount);
select.groupBy(exOperatorId, exOperatorName, exMoment, exType);

TypedQuery<CarTaskByOperator> query = entityManager.createQuery(select);
List<CarTaskByOperator> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

`CarTaskByOperator` is class (not `@Entity` class) to obtain the result and work with it latter.

```
public class CarTaskByOperator implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private long operatorId;
private String operatorName;
private String carTaskMoment;
private String carIncidenceTypeName;
private long amount;

public CarTaskByOperator(){
}

public CarTaskByOperator(final long operatorId, final String operatorName, final String taskMoment, final String typeName, final long amount) {
    this.operatorId = operatorId;
    this.operatorName = operatorName;
    this.carTaskMoment = taskMoment;
    this.carIncidenceTypeName = typeName;
    this.amount = amount;
}
...
}
```

When I run this code, the query I obtain is the following:

```
select
    cartaskope0_.operator_id as col_1_0_,
    appusr1_.name as col_2_0_,
    to_char(cartaskope0_.moment, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as col_3_0_,
    carinciden4_.description as col_4_0_,
    count(cartaskope0_.incidence_id) as col_0_0_
from
    car_task_operation_hist cartaskope0_ 
    cross join app_usr appusr1_ 
    cross join car_task cartask2_ 
    cross join car_incidences carinciden3_ 
    cross join car_incidence_type_cfg carinciden4_
where
    cartaskope0_.operator_id=appusr1_.app_usr
    and cartaskope0_.cpy_code=appusr1_.cpy_code
    and cartaskope0_.cpy_code=cartask2_.cpy_code
    and cartaskope0_.incidence_id=cartask2_.incidence_id
    and cartaskope0_.node_code=cartask2_.node_code
    and cartaskope0_.node_type=cartask2_.node_type
    and cartask2_.cpy_code=carinciden3_.cpy_code
    and cartask2_.incidence_id=carinciden3_.incidence_id
    and cartask2_.locator=carinciden3_.locator
    and cartask2_.node_code=carinciden3_.node_code
    and cartask2_.node_type=carinciden3_.node_type
    and carinciden3_.cpy_code=carinciden4_.cpy_code
    and carinciden3_.type=carinciden4_.type
group by
    cartaskope0_.operator_id ,
    appusr1_.name ,
    to_char(cartaskope0_.moment, 'DD-MM-YYYY') ,
    carinciden4_.description
```

When I run the query it works in SQL IDE, but in Java I get the next error:

```
 2019-11-27 10:13:41,069 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) SQL Error: 979, SQLState: 42000
 2019-11-27 10:13:41,080 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) ORA-00979: no es una expresión GROUP BY

 2019-11-27 10:13:41,093 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/api/car-task-operation-hist/get-by-operator] due to exception [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
    at etr04.conc.car.controller.CarTaskOperationHistController.getByOperator(CarTaskOperationHistController.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at etr04.conc.users.repository.jwt.JwtAuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthTokenFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1507)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    ... 126 more
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: no es una expresión GROUP BY

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 141 more
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution.

After some changes and tries, what I see is that Hibernate may has a problem with the use of CriteriaBuilder.literal in Groupby. So how I solve it is with the next code:

```
final CriteriaBuilder critBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<CarTaskByOperator> critQuery = critBuilder.createQuery(CarTaskByOperator.class);
final Root<CarTaskOperationHist> root = critQuery.from(CarTaskOperationHist.class);

// Select and Group Expressions
final Expression<Long> exOperatorId = root.get("operatorId");
final Expression<String> exOperatorName = root.get("operatorBean").get("name");
final Expression<String> exMoment = critBuilder.function("TRUNC", String.class, root.get("moment"));
final Expression<String> exType = root.get("carTaskBean").get("carIncidenceBean").get("carIncidenceTypeBean").get("description");
final Expression<Long> exAmount = critBuilder.count(root.get("incidenceId"));

final CriteriaQuery<CarTaskByOperator> select = critQuery.multiselect(exOperatorId, exOperatorName, exMoment, exType, exAmount);
select.groupBy(exOperatorId, exOperatorName, exMoment, exType);

TypedQuery<CarTaskByOperator> query = entityManager.createQuery(select);
List<CarTaskByOperator> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

I use TRUNC function instead of TO_CHAR and I change CarTaskByOperator´s CarTaskMoment type to Date, like next:
    public class CarTaskByOperator implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private long operatorId;
private String operatorName;
private Date carTaskMoment;
private String carIncidenceTypeName;
private long amount;

public CarTaskByOperator(){
}

public CarTaskByOperator(final long operatorId, final String operatorName, final Date taskMoment, final String typeName, final long amount) {
    this.operatorId = operatorId;
    this.operatorName = operatorName;
    this.carTaskMoment = taskMoment;
    this.carIncidenceTypeName = typeName;
    this.amount = amount;
}
...
}
```

Thx all again.

Answer (score 1):

Just google for the error code [ORA-00979](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression/), Oracle is quite handy in that regard.

> Any SELECT expression that is not included in the GROUP function must be listed in the GROUP BY clause.

So to answer the initial question: Yes, it is very much pssible (and commin, I guess) to group-by multiple columns ;) add *carinciden4_.description* to your group-by statement.

Comment: Thanks Nikolas for answer. I think the problem is in Hibernate library, because, like you say, the generated SQL has all the params in SELECT expression in GROUP function, and when I test it in DBeaver (for example) it works well. It´s the reason because I say that can maybe be a problem with my code or in Hibernate library.

Comment: oh you're right, I got that wrong. Hm, the criteria query looks fine, though ;D